# Meaning of mount in software engineering

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, programming

What does "mount" mean in the following sentence:

> If you **mount** a local folder inside a docker container

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_(computing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mount in this (IT) context is a technical word meaning to make the local folder available to the computer, so that appears to be within the docker container. In IT the word comes from when a disk or a tape needed to be put into place (mounted like a picture in a frame) before it could be used.